# como fazer uma busca equivalente a count com group by no pymongo

Tags: python, select, mongodb, pymongo

tenho uma collection mais ou menos assim:

```
[{"cidade": "São Paulo", "uf": "SP"},
{"cidade": "Campinas", "uf": "SP"},
{"cidade": "são lourenço", "uf": "MG"}]
```

E quero fazer uma busca usando pymongo equivalente a:

```
select uf, count(*) as qtd from cidades group by uf
```

Comment: De cabeça é alguma coisa mais ou menos assim `db.cidades.aggregate([{"$group": {"_id": "$uf"}}, {"$count": "qtd"}])` .Edite a pergunta e adicione um [MCVE] mostrando o que já fez ou já tentou, mostre o resultado que está obtendo. Pois existem diversas formas de fazer essa consulta e com um código testável em mãos, além de receber uma resposta testada é possível fazer a análise de performance nas diversas opções.

Comment: Na verdade o certo seria `db.cidades.aggregate([{"$group": {"_id": "$uf", "qtd": {"$count": {}}}}])`, só para constar.

Comment: @Rfroes87, obrigado pelo esclarecimento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com base em meus testes e nos comentários da comunidade uma forma de realizar essa busca é:

```
db.cidades.aggregate([{"$group": {"_id": "$uf", "qtd": {"$sum": 1}}}])
```

O resultado obtido foi:

```
{'_id': 'SP', 'qtd': 2}
{'_id': 'MG', 'qtd': 1}
```

Isso já atende a minha necessidade.